# PIL/Pillow not showing image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am currently trying to create a simple picture with PIL using Google Colab. 
However, there is no output of the picture

Version is 5.3.0

```
!pip install -U Pillow==5.3.0
from PIL import Image
print(PIL.PILLOW_VERSION)

im= Image.new("RGB", (128, 128), "#FF0000")
im.show()
```

[image: output]

**edit: changing "im.show()" to "im" does the trick. It works now**

Comment: This causes an error since you don't import the `PIL` module entirely, so `PIL` isn't in scope for `PIL.PILLOW_VERSION`. Get rid of that line. It works for me if I fix that.

Comment: which line do you mean exactly? I have also tried out importing PIL only, excluding any of the first 3 lines, tried it without installing version 5.3 (It was 4.2.0 in that case)
Can you please post the code that works for you as an answer to the question? Thanks

Comment: Everything but the first and third line. `from PIL import Image; im = Image.new("RGB", (128, 128), "#FF0000"); im.show()`. That shows a red square. I don't want to answer though since it isn't clear what exactly the problem is. If that code doesn't work, it's something other than what I thought it was.

Comment: I did a factory reset on the colab notebook, tried the code. Doesn't work. Are you using colab as well?

Comment: Hm, okay. If I just write "im" it works... weird

Comment: Nope, Pycharm. So it's your environment, not the code. `show` attempts to create a window, which it may be blocking. Try saving the image to file using `img.save(path)`.

Comment: Yes, I later used `save(path)` to save the picture to my drive folder. `im` also stopped returning the picture as it reached a size of 5000*5000 pixel. Still sucks that `im.show` does not work